# Rikulo-Stream crashes daily with -"SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32"

Tags: rikulo

I have a simple web app (http://www.webdungeon2.org) (6 pages) running on the latest (April 2014) version of Rikulo Stream (Ubuntu 13.04), Dart 1.2 and I get the following error when browsing (i think):

```
Uncaught Error: SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32, address = 0.0.0.0, port = 80
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32, address = 0.0.0.0, port = 80
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:700)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:23)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:32)
#3      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:36)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:119)
```

The server crashes and then I restart it. This has happened 3 times in 3 days.

I also get these (which do NOT crash the site):

```
2014-04-09 15:07:33.394:stream:5
SHOUT: [/MY_WEB_PAGE] HttpException: Trying to set 'Transfer-Encoding: Chunked' on HTTP 1.0 headers
#0      _HttpHeaders.chunkedTransferEncoding= (http_headers.dart:142)
#1      Rsp.init (package:stream/src/rsp_util.dart:25:15)
#2      demo (file:///mytool/webdungeon/web/webapp/demo.rsp.dart:10:16)
#3      _StreamServer._handle (package:stream/src/server_impl.dart:92:39)
#4      _StreamServer._startChannel.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:stream/src/server_impl.dart:310:16)
#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:717)
#6      _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:449)
#7      _CustomizedZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:654)
#8      _BaseZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:569)
......
......
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE -  12 April**

Problem still occurs on Dart 1.3, but error code is different

```
Uncaught Error: SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104, address = 0.0.0.0, port = 80
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104, address = 0.0.0.0, port = 80
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:713)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:23)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:32)
#3      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:36)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:119)
```

Serge

**UPDATE -  28 April**

The problem seems to have been resolved in Dart SDK version 1.3.3. My server has been running for  2 days without a hitch.

Serge

Comment: Can you update with the source code in question? I'd like to investigate this issue a bit closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you upgrade to Dart 1.3? The problem shall be caused by [Issue 17468](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17468), and it was fixed in Dart 1.3.

> For the issue of `HttpException...Chunked`, I don't have the experience of it. You have to check Dart API, or make a simple case to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, upgraded to Dart 1.3 two days ago and so far no more crashes. I will wait a few days and then confirm that it fixed the issue.

Comment: Server running Dart 1.3 just crashed with a similar error "OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104"

Comment: Can you report to dartbug.com? It is a server issue.

Comment: OK. will try. I have a suspicion that chunk HTTP 1.0 error is caused by robots scanning site. I had previously disallowed access to some subdirectories. Now set robots.txt to  disallow: [blank].

Comment: As described in [Issue 17468](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17468), it was fixed a few hours ago. Please give it a try, when it (r35071) is ready at [here](http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/raw/latest/)

Comment: Fixed with Dart SDK 1.3.3 (64 bit linux). Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

The fix for [issue 17468](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17468) contained a bug. Streams belongs to the zone where they are listened to, not created. I've fixed this mistake with [r35071](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/detail?r=35071).

While this will not fix the 1.3 binary, it should be possible to check out the 1.3 source and apply this patch.